# how to set text to textview from a string Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

how can i set string arraylist "mylist[0]" as a text to a textview ?

```
Intent in= getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> mylist = in.getStringArrayListExtra("rname");

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText(mylist[0]);//getting error here saying "array type expected"
    }
```

Comment: replace with mylist.get(0)

Comment: before asking question on SO, please do some research work. Search for how to retrieve values from arraylist, you will find thousands of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this code

```
t.setText(mylist[0]);
```

with

```
t.setText(mylist.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     List<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

        Editable s = editText.getText();

            char c;
            for(int i=0; i< editText.length(); i++){

                char result = s.charAt(i);
                 textView.append(String.valueOf(result));
               mStrings.add(String.valueOf(result));

                try{

                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    editText.setText(mStrings.get(1));
                }catch(Exception e){}

    }
```